# Configuring RollingFileAppender in log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm working on a set of web services and we'd like to have a daily rotated log.

I'm trying to get `org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender` from the log4j extras companion working, since the documentation suggests this is best for production environments.

I have both the main log4J library (`log4j-1.2.15.jar`) and the log4j extras library (`apache-log4j-extras-1.1.jar`) on the classpath.

I have the following configuration for the appender in the `log4j.properties` file:

```
### SOAP Request Appender
log4j.appender.request=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.request.File=SOAPmessages.log
log4j.appender.request.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.request.RollingPolicy.ActiveFileName =SOAPmessages-%d.log
log4j.appender.request.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=SOAPmessages-%d.log.zip
log4j.appender.request.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.request.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

However, when I start the web service with log4j in debug mode I get these error messages:

```
log4j: Parsing appender named "request".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "request".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "request".
log4j: Setting property [file] to [/logs/SOAPmessages.log].
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [rollingPolicy] to value "org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy". 
log4j:WARN Please set a rolling policy for the RollingFileAppender named 'request'
log4j: Parsed "request" options.
```

I've found documentation about how to configure this appender a little sparse, so **can anyone help me fix my configuration?**

**EDIT0:** Added debug mode output, rather than just the standard warnings

Comment: To troubleshoot this problem, I think you could try to turn on Log4j debug mode to see if there are any more detailed error messages

Comment: Not an answer, just a suggestion. You really should look into logback. Its so much more flexible that log4j.

Comment: FYI:  This problem was fixed in log4j v1.2.16.   it now supports setting rollingPolicy via the properties file.
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36384

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update: at least as early as 2013 (see Mubashar's comment) this started working.

---

According to [Log4jXmlFormat](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat) you cannot configure it with log4j.properties, but only using the XML config format:

> Note that TimeBasedRollingPolicy can only be configured with xml, not log4j.properties

Unfortunately, the example log4j.xml they provide doesn't work either:

```
log4j:ERROR Parsing error on line 14 and column 76
log4j:ERROR Element type "rollingPolicy" must be declared.
...
log4j:WARN Please set a rolling policy for the RollingFileAppender named 'FILE'
```

Comment: I see, didn't notice that in any of the documentation I read, nor any links to the wiki which would have been helpful. Thanks for pointing that out +1

Comment: This might be true on the date you answered but it is working fine with log4j.properties file, atleast for me

Comment: There is a "log4j-extras" package from apache, where you can find the "rollingPolicy" defined. It will solve many of your problems

Comment: @toolbear : I beg to differ because I am using log4j.properties and it's working fine. Is it the case that they have added the support later.

Comment: @SagarKharab answer is out of date. In 2011 it didn't work. As early as 2013 (see Mubashar's comment) it worked. I've updated my answer to indicate this.

Answer (score 66):

I had a similar problem and just found a way to solve it (by single-stepping through `log4j-extras` source, no less...)

The good news is that, unlike what's written everywhere, it turns out that **you actually CAN configure TimeBasedRollingPolicy** using log4j.properties (XML config not needed!  At least in versions of log4j >1.2.16 see this [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36384))

Here is an example:

```
log4j.appender.File = org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.File.rollingPolicy = org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.File.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern = logs/worker-${instanceId}.%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmm}.log
```

BTW the `${instanceId}` bit is something I am using on Amazon's EC2 to distinguish the logs from all my workers -- I just need to set that property before calling `PropertyConfigurator.configure()`, as follow:

```
p.setProperty("instanceId", EC2Util.getMyInstanceId());
PropertyConfigurator.configure(p);
```

Comment: Recently, I've created a [patch](http://pastebin.com/DugN7AiZ) to also allow for recursive directories to be configured. You can for example store daily zipped log files in monthly subdirectories like so: `log4j.appender.File.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=Logs/%d{yyyyMM}/ServerLog_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.zip`. The needed directories will be created by log4j correctly when needed.

Answer (score 22):

Faced more issues while making this work. Here are the details:

1. To download and add `apache-log4j-extras-1.1.jar` in the classpath, didn't notice this at first.
2. The `RollingFileAppender` should be `org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender` instead of `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender`. This can give the error: `log4j:ERROR No output stream or file set for the appender named [file].`
3. We had to upgrade the log4j library from `log4j-1.2.14.jar` to `log4j-1.2.16.jar`.

Below is the appender configuration which worked for me:

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
        <rollingPolicy name="file"
            class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="logs/MyLog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log.gz" />
            <!-- The below param will keep the live update file in a different location-->
            <!-- param name="ActiveFileName" value="current/MyLog.log" /-->
        </rollingPolicy>

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Was somehow completely blind to the difference between o.a.log4j.RFAppender and o.a.log4j.rolling.RFAppender. Needed someone to point out the obvious.

Comment: I have log4j-1.2.17.jar but it has no following package org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender

Comment: @yatinbc, get log4j extras package.

Answer (score 4):

Toolbear74 is right log4j.XML is required.
In order to get the XML to validate the `<param>` tags need to be BEFORE the `<rollingPolicy>`
I suggest setting a logging threshold `<param name="threshold" value="info"/>`

When Creating a Log4j.xml file don't forget to to copy the log4j.dtd into the same location.

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>
<!-- Daily Rolling File Appender that compresses old files -->
  <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender" >
     <param name="threshold" value="info"/>
     <rollingPolicy name="file"  
                      class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="FileNamePattern" 
               value="${catalina.base}/logs/myapp.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz"/>
        <param name="ActiveFileName" value="${catalina.base}/logs/myapp.log"/>
     </rollingPolicy>
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout" >
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
               value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p - %-26.26c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <priority value="debug"></priority>
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Considering that your setting a `FileNamePattern` and an `ActiveFileName` I think that setting a `File` property is redundant and possibly even erroneous

Try renaming your log4j.properties and dropping in a log4j.xml similar to my example and see what happens.

Comment: Yep, it needed to be configured using XML +1

Comment: I'd rather will put one additional library to the classpath than use XML for this task, becouse I have already a lot of configuration in properties style, so rewritting all just because one appender is not logical

Answer (score 4):

Regarding error: `log4j:ERROR Element type "rollingPolicy" must be declared`

1. Use a log4j.jar version newer than log4j-1.2.14.jar, which has a `log4j.dtd` defining `rollingPolicy`.
2. of course you also need `apache-log4j-extras-1.1.jar`
3. Check if any other third party jars you are using perhaps have an older version of log4j.jar packed inside.
   If so, make sure your log4j.jar comes first in the order before the third party containing the older log4j.jar.

Answer (score 2):

In Log4j2, the "extras" lib is not mandatory any more. Also the configuration format has changed.

An example is provided in the [Apache documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties)

```
property.filename = /foo/bar/test.log

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = /foo/bar/rolling/test1-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5


logger.rolling.name = com.example.my.class
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a bad package name

```
org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
```

The correct one is:

```
org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
```

Comment: Actually, both are valid package names. One refers to the implementation of a RollingFileAppender in the [main log4j library](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html), whilst the other refers to the implementation in the [log4j extras library](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html), which provides a variety of alternative filters and appenders. The implementation in the main package specifically recommends using the extras implementation.