# log4j: Rolling logs into .gz file with DailyRollingFileAppender using TimeBasedRollingPolicy

Tags: log4j

The current system is working as expected and the log files are rolled once an hr according to the logic below:

```
log4j.appender.oozie=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.oozie.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.oozie.File=${oozie.log.dir}/oozie.log
log4j.appender.oozie.Append=true
log4j.appender.oozie.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.oozie.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I can understand that rolling of log file directly into a compressed file(.gz or .zip) is possible with RollingFileAppender(rolling based on file size) using TimeBasedRollingPolicy. I'm using DailyRollingFileAppender(time based rolling) and would like to achieve compression with that. I modified my properties as follows. But that doesnt work.

```
log4j.appender.oozie=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.oozie.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.oozie.File=${oozie.log.dir}/oozie.log
log4j.appender.oozie.Append=true
log4j.appender.oozie.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.oozie.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=foo.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.gz
log4j.appender.oozie.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.oozie.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Any pointers would be highly appreciated. Here are some relevant links.

[Configuring RollingFileAppender in log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117758/configuring-rollingfileappender-in-log4j)

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html

Comment: have you found a solution for that? i see the same

Answer (score 3):

Pardon my surprise, but at the exact link you gave above it says in the accepted answer:

> Note that TimeBasedRollingPolicy can only be configured with xml, not log4j.properties

Have you tried rewriting your configuration to XML format?

Comment: Thanks for your response..In the link I had posted, one of the responses says "This problem was fixed in log4j v1.2.16. it now supports setting rollingPolicy via the properties file. issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36384". I havent tried rewriting in XML since that would be a big change(need to rewrite for multiple loggers that are already there with different rolling intervals) and hence we would try to achieve this using properties file itself.

Answer (score 2):

please try the following, it works for me:

```
log4j.rootLogger=CONSOLE,file


log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE..layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.file.Encoding=UTF-8

log4j.appender.file.File=/path to your logs/logs/log_file.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/path to your                 logs/logs/log_file%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}.log
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM-dd@HH:mm:ss} %-5p (%13F:%L) %3x - %m%n
```

Comment: Doesn't work on commons-logging-1.1.1 (with log4j.log4j:1.2.12), the error is
log4j:WARN No such property [rollingPolicy] in org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [datePattern] in org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [datePattern] in org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [rollingPolicy] in org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.