# Archiving previous log files using log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am currently using `rollingFileAppender` and rolling files based in time.

I want to roll log files based on date so that I have one log file per day. (I am assuming this can be done using `dailyRollingFileAppender`.)

Also I want to archive previous log files so that I have log files for 15 days uncompressed and for another 15 days in an archived format so that one zipped file contains log files for 15 days.

Can I configure this using `log4j.properties` alone ?

Comment: This is the closest I found: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3329385/422353

Answer (score 1):

An external option is 'logrotated' which has rules to do what you need. Example conf files can be had in /etc/logrotate.d/*. For example:

```
cat /etc/logrotate.d/dpkg    
/var/log/dpkg.log {
    monthly
    rotate 12
    compress
    delaycompress
    missingok
    notifempty
    create 644 root root
}
/var/log/alternatives.log {
    monthly
    rotate 12
    compress
    delaycompress
    missingok
    notifempty
    create 644 root root
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aimon. I hadn't thought of that. But, I have the application deployed in several locations(testing, deployment) and ideally want to maintain the same configuration. Which is why I want to configure it via log4j.

Answer (score 1):

For doing this you can use crontab and schedule it to archive or zip the log files.

You can do something like this in your crontab file-

```
0 0 15 * * find /your-folder -name '*trace.log' -mtime -15 | xargs gzip -v9
```

Comment: And if the program is running on windows then?

Comment: In windows you can use the task scheduler.