# log4j. Rollover each hour, zip daily

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Can I configure log4j to rollover each hour, then compress all the daily log-files into one zip (so that zip contains 24 log-files).

Ideally I'd like to zip files only for those days which are one week old and earlier. But that's another part of the question.

Answer (score 9):

You probably want to use a [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html). To roll them hourly, for example, you'd use a DatePattern of `'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH`. For a log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.appender.myAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
...
```

Or for your programmatic configuration:

```
DailyRollingFileAppender appender = new DailyRollingFileAppender();
appender.setDatePattern("'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH");

Logger root = Logger.getRootLogger();
root.addAppender(appender);
```

Unfortunately, using a DailyRollingFileAppender means that you can't limit the file size - this could be problematic if you have tons of logs in the given rolled period.

To compress take a look to: [compress-log4j-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329385/compress-log4j-files)

Comment: well, do you mean that combining DailyRollingFileAppender with TimeBasedRollingPolicy (value="logs/appname.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.zip"), it will be able to pick up all of those 24 files daily and pack into one zip-archive?

Comment: sorry idk, you have to try it