# how can i minimize the stack trace in eclipse java tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I debug a java app in eclipse during development, the problems are isolated to my actual code in whatever app I am debugging.  But yet the stack trace lists every class in every jar included in the buildpath that is called when the error is thrown.  This means it takes much longer every single time to sort through the stack trace to find just the lines of code in the classes I have built myself in my app.  I want to stop wasting this time.

**How can I set eclipse so that the stack trace only includes classes and line numbers that are in code written in the project itself, and not in the included jars?**

Comment: then i think you need to use some logging framework to achieve this. afaik, eclipse only has a stack trace filter for junit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606614/cleaning-noise-out-of-java-stack-traces

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568486/how-to-reduce-logs-size

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote an Open Source Library that has one of the utilities that solves this exact problem. the Utility allows you to specify a particular package prefix and then allows you to smartly filter out irrelevant lines from your stack trace. Also you can control by boolean flag if you want to get a full stacktrace or filtered one. I use this feature in all of my projects and am very happy with it. The library is available as Maven artifact (source code, javadoc and actual library) and as a project on github. The Utility can be plugged in easily as a Spring bean. Here is a article that explains in detail how it works how to use it and how to get it both as Maven artifact and as project from github: [Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman). Look for paragraph **"Stacktrace noise filter"**

Comment: I cannot validate this now because I am working on other things. But I am marking+1 for giving a possible option.

Comment: As I mentioned, this solution has been battle tested. But I will be very happy to hear feedback whenever you can provide one. You can do it here or contact me directly by email (provided in the article mentioned in my answer)

Comment: The original poster's request was for an independent third party to validate the advertising claims made in this answer. I did not ask for the advertiser to amplify the advertisement.

Comment: @CodeMed - I am a bit confused. It looks like it was your question to begin with (i.e. you are the original poster). In any case my comment wasn't meant to be "in your face" pushing ad. My apologies if that's how it sounds

Comment: The advertiser is requested to stop adding noise pollution in these comments. An independent outside party is requested to validate the advertiser's claims.