# Cassandra: How to archive the log file

Tags: logging, cassandra, archive

I've installed Cassandra 2.0.11 on Ubuntu machine.

The logging configuration is default. The location of the log files are in

```
/var/log/cassandra/
```

Also, the log files are already in a rotating mode.

How can I configure the log files to be zipped?
So it won't consume a lot of disk storage.

Answer (score 1):

**For Cassandra 2.0 and prior**

If you followed the [docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configOutputLog_t.html) from here, you probably seen the compress command. By default logrotate will compress the rotated files with gzip.The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) says you can also set a `compresscmd` and `compressext` to use your own compression application (i.e zip). You could probably put together your own compression script.

Example:

```
/var/log/cassandra/output.log {
        size 1k
        copytruncate
        create
        compress
        compresscmd /bin/bzip2
        compressext .bz2
        rotate 4
}
```

**For Cassandra 2.1 and later**

According to the [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FixedWindowRollingPolicy), you should end your `fileNamePattern` in the `rollingPolicy` with `zip` or `gz`. Just like in the [example](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configLoggingLevels_r.html) here.

The Cassandra documentation, on the second link also says:

> The default policy rolls the system.log file after the size exceeds
>   20MB. Archives are compressed in zip format. Logback names the log
>   files system.log.1.zip, system.log.2.zip, and so on. For more
>   information, see logback documentation.

Comment: Logback was introduced in Cassandra 2.1, it was Log4J in Cassandra 2.0

Comment: Ok, didn't notice that... I started a new project recently and started with 2.1, so I mechanically answered like this...

Answer (score 1):

**The answer applies only for Cassandra 2.0 and prior.**

Cassandra 2.0 and prior are using log4j as the logging API.
It answer the need for:

1. Simple logging
2. Rotating log files

It does not answer the need to zip\archive the old files in order to save storage place.

In order to support zip of the old log files, you need to use *log4j-extensions* (see [compress log4j log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329385/compress-log4j-files))
If you really want to activate it in Cassandra you need to do the following:

1. install it from the source code
2. Download log4j-extras and add it to the Cassandra lib directory
3. Compile the project with maven

Obviously, the is a slim chance that you'll do that. Too much trouble.

There is a simple solution: (Only works on Linux OS)

1. Configure Cassandra to use simple logging
2. Configure **logrotate** daemon to handle the log files

**Configure Cassandra to use simple logging**

```
sudo vi /etc/cassandra/log4j-server.properties
```

Change the following in this file:

```
# Add the new Appender to the rootLogger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,stdout,F,R

# Mark the following configuration (all the RollingFileAppender)
# rolling log file
#log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.R.maxFileSize=1MB
#log4j.appender.R.maxBackupIndex=3
#log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] %d{ISO8601} %F (line %L) %m%n

#log4j.appender.R.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
#log4j.appender.R.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=cassandra.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.gz
#log4j.appender.R.RollingPolicy.ActiveFileName =cassandra.log

# Edit the next line to point to your logs directory
#log4j.appender.R.File=/var/log/cassandra/cassandra.log
########################################################

# Add the new File Appender
# file appender
# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.F=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.F.File=/var/log/cassandra/cassandra.log
# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.F.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.F.layout.conversionPattern=%5p [%t] %d{ISO8601} %F (line %L) %m%n
```

Now Cassandra logs only to one file and not rotate it. Next...

**Configure logrotate daemon to handle the log files**

If you really wants to know what is logrotate: [Understanding logrotate utility](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/understanding-logrotate-utility)

Do the following:

```
sudo vi /etc/logrotate.d/cassandra
```

Add the following data to the file:

```
/var/log/cassandra/cassandra.log {
    daily
    rotate 50
    size 100M
    copytruncate
    compress
    delaycompress
    missingok
    notifempty
    create 644 cassandra cassandra
}
```

And that's it. From now on, logrotate will take care of your log files and keep the overall storage to no more than 5GB.

If you want to change the storage size, configure the *rotate* and *size* as you see fit.