# Dealing with extremely bad practice, Jboss5, log4j, unhandled exceptions, drowning in useless log data

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j, jboss5.x

I'm a systems Engineer, and I've got multiple JBOSS5 instances, and a complete mess of deployed wars. I know the log4J.xml file, to a decent degree, and have it sending all logs to localhost rsyslog.  Now the problem...

Basically the code could be a textbook example of extremely horrific practices, regular expected situations go unhandled, and are sent to log4j as WARN/INFO or ERROR.... Basically the entire logs have become meaningless and wasteful, and I'm unable to get the developers to do anything to fix this... their may be a future time I can make my case, but I'm totally stuck with this pile.

I simply no longer want to accept 150MiB of nonsense being forwarding to centralized logging, the whole thing has made even identifying MY own system problems difficult.  I know everything I can do on the system level, very well in fact, and have done everything to isolate and mitigate the consequences... but thats not enough, what can I do now on the Jboss/log4J/Java side?

I can't cut off all logging, I need to at least have the parts they didn't screw up logged.  So with that said, How do I stop these... and what is even the correct name for this type of log output?

```
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:94)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:152)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.StringRequestEntity.writeRequest(StringRequestEntity.java:146)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
```

Is there anyway I can somehow just get rid of all the lines that start with `at`?  Is that a debugging feature of some sort, they have these in production build by nature?  Really?  I mean if i had the error message, and just none of the `at` lines, i'd be much more comfortable.

Comment: The stack trace is equally as important as the exception name that was thrown. Don't erase it. Logs are useless without it.

Comment: The lines you asked about are part of a "stack trace".  These are extremely useful for debugging, but should rarely, if ever, be emitted by a robust application.  If your applications are logging a lot of these then you're right that they are a mess.  The correct Java-side solution, however, is to fix the application bugs that are allowing predictable exceptions to go uncaught, which you say isn't going to happen soon.

Comment: @Kon , They are deeply detrimental to identifying system problems, so they are far worse than merely useless.  I'd also agree with not disabling them, if I had a developer team that gave a crap about handling their exceptions..... but  this is not where I'm at, and if the two are equally important... then the correct logic would make them equally useless.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, Belive me John, I know how they should work in good or even 'passible' practice... but we are so far beyond that point, and 'a lot of these' is an understatement, i'm talking half the logs are including these, well except the ones produced by open source developers.  If my logs were sorta even halfway like a passable lib, I'd never even want to remove them... But the developers plainly don't even care, and they can see this mess anytime they want out of production.

Comment: If the issue on YOUR system is only due to logs size, have you tried to make Log4j (or something else) ZIP these logs? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329385, knowing that logs get usually very well compressed). Else, you can maybe identify some classes/packages that you want to filter out (both ideas can be performed using only Log4j configuration file)

Comment: @xav the problem isn't the strait log size, it's the overall worthlessness of my logging, and much of it due to the microscopic ratio of value/nonsense.   The fact is, I'd gladly process tons of logs, if they actually provided value...I'm trying to find a way to bring back their value again using log4j, so they become an asset instead of a time suck.