# Why are logfiles not compressed with this log4j configuration?

Tags: java, log4j, compression

I have almost tried everything but log4j seems to not compress the log file. I am using 1.2.17 jars for log4j and log4j extras. Cant seem to understand whats wrong . it simply creates a gz file but thats a normal file without compression
log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender"> 
<rollingPolicy name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy"> 
<param name="ActiveFileName" value="${catalina.home}/logs/broker.log" />
<param name="FileNamePattern" value="=${catalina.home}/logs/broker-.%d{yyyyMMdd-HH}.log.gz" />
</rollingPolicy> 

<triggeringPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
<param name="MaxFileSize" value="10000"/>
</triggeringPolicy>

<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%"/>
</layout>

</appender>
<root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Should giving the file name a `.gz` extension compress the file automagically. I would have thought it would be a setting if not a different appender.

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329385/compress-log4j-files

Comment: log4j applies automatic file compression if the value of the fileNamePattern option ends with .gz or .zip

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my own question this is how I made it work

```
#Worked with 2.17 version
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.maxIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.file.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=10000
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${catalina.home}/logs/broker-%i.log.gz
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=${catalina.home}/logs/broker.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Comment: This link helped me! http://how.vndemy.com/java/log4j/1164-how-to-configure-log4j-using-log4j-properties/#7_Rotate_038_Archiving_File_On_Size

Comment: add apache-log4j-extras:1.2.7 and use the configuration in the link above