# Log4j Compress/Zip multiple log files

Tags: xml, configuration, log4j, zip, compression

I've got multiple log files, how can I compress/zip ALL these at the end of the day using log4j XMLconfiguration?

The goal is to zip up multiple log files at the end of the day essentially.
Not just time based however, also size based

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compress Log4j files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329385/compress-log4j-files)

Comment: no because i want size and time based