# How can I create a zip archive from a log4j log file automatically?

Tags: log4j

below is my log4j.properties file

```
 log4j.rootCategory= ALL,roll
 log4j.appender.roll=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.roll.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
 log4j.appender.roll.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=log/worker.log
 log4j.appender.roll.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=worker.%d{yyyyMMddHHmm}.log.zip
 log4j.appender.roll.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.roll.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{DATE}] [%p] - %m%n
```

Comment: What do you mean by archive?

Comment: making zip file of my log file..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compress Log4j files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329385/compress-log4j-files)