# Collect logs ZIP and upload to Http service without temp file

Tags: java, jira, nio, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to create a utility that collect a set of logs zip them and attach them to jira.

I am planning to use httpclient 4.5. (has NIO support) The jira API is not an issue here.

I would like to stream files directly from file system via zip stream and upload to jira without the need to create a temporary zip file on the file system.

I found the java API confusing in such case and failed to figure out the usage.
Attentively it looks like such case is a good candidate for java NIO usage (maybe a channel?) but failed to find a good example.

As a starting point I created an example that upload one file from but I am failing to take it to the next step of Zip stream.

```
HttpClient httpClient = createHttpClient();


final String issueUriAttach = issueUri + "/" + "attachments";

HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(issueUriAttach);
final FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("README.md");
InputStream in = new InputStream() {
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        return fileInputStream.read(b,off,len);
    }
};
InputStreamBody inputStreamBody = new InputStreamBody(in,"README.csv");
HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .setContentType(ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        .addPart("file", inputStreamBody)
        .build();
postRequest.setHeader(getAuthHeader());
postRequest.setHeader(getNocheckHeader());

postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

As I said I am not limited to java I/O java NIO is an option as well..

Comment: you can use log4j library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329385/compress-log4j-files

Comment: Thanks @koutuk. This is an external utility. It should collect logs create by the application we test and does not create the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write the data to a `ZipOutputStream` in a separate thread and pipe it to an `InputStream` for the HttpClient to read from.

```
/**
 * Zip a collection of files and pipe the output to an InputStream 
 */
public static InputStream zipSource(Collection<Path> paths) throws IOException {
    // Pipe pair. We zip to the output stream in a separate thread. The data is
    // then available to be read from the input stream.
    PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
    PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(out);

    // Zip the file to the input stream in another thread
    zipExecutor.execute(() -> {
        try {
            zip(paths, out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Zip failed " + e);
        }
    });

    return in;
}

/**
 * Zip a collection of files to an output stream
 */
public static void zip(Collection<Path> paths, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    try (ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(out)) {
        for (Path path : paths) {
            zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path.getFileName().toString()));
            Files.copy(path, zout);
            zout.closeEntry();
        }
    }
}

private static final Executor zipExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(r -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(r, "zip task");
    t.setDaemon(true);
    return t;
});
```

Comment: looks interesting, I will give it a try. Although it looks like one file per upload.

Comment: I've split the two concerns in the example. One method handles the zip and the other exposes the output through an `InputStream`.