# Log4j 1.2.17 - How to do log rolling based on size

Tags: log4j

I would like my logfile to roll when it reaches to a given size (lets say 100MB) and rolled file should be archived(.gz)  Also, the zip file should have current time stamp in its name.

Is it possible to achieve this using log4j 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the parameter `maxFileSize` and `maxBackupIndex` for a `RollingFileAppender`

For compression check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3329513/1811730

This link can help : [Rotate & Archiving File On Size](http://how.vndemy.com/java/log4j/1164-how-to-configure-log4j-using-log4j-properties/#7_Rotate_038_Archiving_File_On_Size)

If you can, don't use log4j 1.2 but see for log4j 2